# Problem with Geojson in choropleth map of India

Tags: pandas, geojson, choropleth

I want to plot a choropleth map using this geojson file for India.
I am getting an error for this.

**This is my Geojson file:**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
    "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
 }
  },
  "features": [  
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      "ID_0": 105,
      "ISO": "IND",
      "NAME_0": "India",
      "ID_1": 1,
        "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "NL_NAME_1": null,
        "VARNAME_1": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands|Andaman et Nicobar|Iihas de Andama e 
Nicobar|Inseln Andamanen und Nikobare",
        "TYPE_1": "Union Territor",
        "ENGTYPE_1": "Union Territory"
      },
       "geometry": {
       "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
      [
        [
```

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
ind_map.choropleth(
geo_data=ind_geo,
data=df,
columns=['States/UTs', '2017'],
key_on='Feature.properties.ID_0',
fill_color='YlOrRd', 
fill_opacity=0.7, 
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='Accident rate in India'
)
```

**I am getting this error:**
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'